# refresh datagridview only if contents change

Tags: datagridview, compare, refresh, datasource

I have a few Datagridviews that are bound to datasources. This data is taken from a Database, and needs to be constantly up to date. (I refresh the Datagridview every second)
This constant refreshing causes some obvious problems in scrolling, selecting, and so on. The data does not change so frequently, only about twice a minute, but when it changes I need the Datagrid to be updated quickly, thus the frequent refresh.

Is there a way to verify quickly (for example by using a hash function or so) to see if the content of the datasource has changed? I would like to avoid comparing each cell/row as it might be too much work for the software for all my datagridviews. Is there a better way?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
DataSet dsBindedToDataGridView = new DataSet(); // Get data from DB & Bind this to DataGridView and persist it.
DataSet dsRetrivedOnRefresh = new DataSet(); //Add code to fetch data from DB

 var result = dsBindedToDataGridView.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Except(dsRetrivedOnRefresh.Tables[0].AsEnumerable(),DataRowComparer.Default);
//Now if result has got any value then data has changed and you need to refresh the data else ignore
```

Comment: does not seem to work.. I am using two datatables instead of datasets, but doing the same. binded datatable is empty, retrive on refresh has one row. result.any returns false.

Comment: Have you not persisted your datatable after binding with DataGridView?

Comment: what does that mean?